# converting from JTextArea to String and back

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jtextarea

For a homework assignment I am tasked with determine how many of each letter are in a sentence. I have already successfully completed the homework using JOptionPane. But I want to display in a JFrame. I am able to convert from the text area input, but am no table to convert from string back to text area display.

:

```
for (short i = 0; i < (output).length(); i++)
                {
                    char temp = Character.toLowerCase((output).charAt(i));
                    if (temp >= 'a' && temp <= 'z')
                        counts[temp - 'a']++;
                }

                for (short i = 0; i < counts.length; i++)
                {
                    output += (char) ('a' + i) + ":\t " + counts[i] + "\n";
                }

                for (short i = 0; i < (input).length(); i++)
                {
                    if ((output).charAt(i) == 'a' || (output).charAt(i) == 'A')
                        count++;
                }
                txaResults.setText(output);
```

Comment: @Little Child. The problem I'm having (I think) is in displaying the results. I think I get the text from the input JTextArea just fine and am able to convert to a string. The logic to determine results alsoappears to be working. The problem is that the "results" JTextArea is not being populated with the results. I'm not sure if that clarifies?

Comment: Have a look at my answer. I guess you wanna show the frequency of the words in a JFrame instead of a JOptionPane, isn't it ?

Comment: @Little Child. <edit>. No, sorry. I am trying to determine how often each letter appears, not words. That logic is working when I simply used JOptionPane, but i'm missing something when trying to convert to JFrame JTextArea

Comment: Your with has been granted. Look at my code below.

Comment: So the gettext() is working `output = txaResults.getText();`. Its the put text (for lack of a better term) that isn't working

Comment: There is a method for "put text".. it's `setText()`

Comment: @user2802785 Was it the placement of the method that was the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try and put the `createAndShowGUI` before the `frame.setVisible`.  You're making the frame visible before your method can perform.

I think this may be your problem:

```
// You're doing this
output = txaResults.getText();

// but I think you want this
input = txaUserInput.getText();

String output = "";

// Your logic here
...
...

txaResults.setText(output);
```

You need to perform the logic from the `txaUserInput` and display it in the `txaResults`

**Edit:**
try this for your logic

```
       int[] counts = new int[26];
       for (short i = 0; i < (input).length(); i++)

       {
                char temp = Character.toLowerCase((input).charAt(i));
                if (temp >= 'a' && temp <= 'z')
                    counts[temp - 'a']++;
       }


       for (short i = 0; i < counts.length; i++)
       {
               output += (char) ('a' + i) + ":\t " + counts[i] + "\n";
       }

       int count = 0;
       for (short i = 0; i < (input).length(); i++)
       {
                if ((input).charAt(i) == 'a' || (input).charAt(i) == 'A')
                    count++;
       }

       output += "" + count;
       txaResults.setText(output);
```

Comment: Thank you. That was a good catch. Unfortunately the output still does not display

Comment: That removed the count altogether (previously it had been '0's). When I change `char[] counts = new char[26];` to `int[] counts = new int[26];` it returns the count display, but still at '0'

Comment: Ok, you're right about the `int` instead of `char`. Also, you never delcared `count`. Do that above your last `for loop` `int count = 0;`, then before `taxResults.setText(output)`, add `output += "" + count;`

Comment: I don't know your desired output, so its kinda hard to give you definite answers

Answer (score 0):

Use `gettext()` to get the text. Then simply loop over the text for words.

You can use a `HashMap<String,Integer>` where `String` is the word and `Integer` is the frequency. When you get the text, just use `split()` to break it down into words. Then, loop over it and add each word to the map.

When you add, first check if the word exists. If not, add it and set the count to one. Next time you encounter the word, increment th counter and add it back to the map.

```
 // the horror logic for calculating
 // word frequency ommitted for
 // sanity's sake

JLabel[] lotOfLabels;
JFrame outputFrame = new JFrame("Final Answer");
Set<String> allMyWords = thatHashMap.keySet();
int totalWords = allMyWords.size();
int count = 0;

outputFrame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
lotOfLabels = new JLabel[totalWords];
for(String each : allMyWords){
    int frequencyOfAWord = allMyWords.get(each);
    lotOfLabels[count] = new JLabel(each + " " + frequencyofAWord);
    outputFrame.getContentPane().add(lotsOfLabels[count]);
    count++;
}

outputFrame.pack();
outputFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
outputFrame.setVisible(true);
```

The code above is for showing the answer in a JFrame